# ERREUR : Unknown column 'Accessoires' in 'where clause'

Tags: java, sql

My query is throwing up this error while i have column Accessoires in table categorie Can anyone see why?

```
public int rechercheParCat(String test) {
    int idcat = 0;
    try {
        String query = "SELECT id_cat FROM categorie WHERE titre="+test;
        PreparedStatement pst = cnx2.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(query);
        idcat = rs.getInt(1);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    return idcat;
}
```

I FIXED IT LIKE THIS:

````
       int idcat = 0;
       try {
           String query = "SELECT id_cat FROM categorie WHERE titre=? ";
           PreparedStatement pst = cnx2.prepareStatement(query);
           pst.setString(1, test);
           ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
           rs.first();
           idcat = rs.getInt(1);
       } catch (SQLException ex) {
           System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
       }

       return idcat;
   }```
````

Comment: Don't concatenate strings in SQL; it's fully open to SQL Injection. Use prepared statements (`?`) instead.

Comment: What's the value of the parameter `test`?

Comment: Don't build SQL this way.  You have made a simple quoting error, which I would point out but that might encourage you to continue building SQL by concatenation, which as has been pointed out is open to SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using bound parameters with a prepared statement likely fixes your bug and also solves the severe security issue.

```
public int rechercheParCat(String test) {
    int idcat = 0;
    try {
        String query = "SELECT id_cat FROM categorie WHERE titre = ?";
        PreparedStatement pst = cnx2.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1, test);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(query);
        idcat = rs.getInt(1);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    return idcat;
}
```

The likely reason your code has failed is that `test` was "Accessoires", so the resulting SQL statement was:

```
SELECT id_cat FROM categorie WHERE titre=Accessoires
```

when in fact it should have been:

```
SELECT id_cat FROM categorie WHERE titre='Accessoires'
```

Even if you added quotes to the concatenated statement, you'd still have a problem. Just imagine what happens if somebody passes a value with quotes, e.g. `O'Connor`. This will just break the code. But a more clever person can inject SQL clauses.